# How to access root state in a reducer in redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a simple counter slice. In increment function I want to access root state. How can I do that?

```
const initialState = {
  value: 1
}

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value++
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you can't. Redux (and not only toolkit) is designed around the idea that your Reducer should only rely on it's own state value and the contents of the action coming in, nothing else.

If you really really need data from another state slice, you probably need to copy that into the action when calling it, but it is usually considered a bad idea.

You might have chosen your slice too small.

Comment: I mean there could be some app-level data like app config settings which will be coming from the server and which I need in rest of the slices.  I don't want to copy the data either. It's just expensive.

Comment: That is how it works. And copying is not expensive, you can put a single reference to something you are interested in there, you don't need to deep-clone everything.